# Disable default animation in TabPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I would like to disable the default animation when I create new Tab.

```
Tab tabA = new Tab();
      tabA.setText("Tab A");
      tabPane.getTabs().add(tabA);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now, when Java 8 is finally out, one has the possibility to disable the animation, using CSS:

```
tabPane.setStyle("-fx-open-tab-animation: NONE; -fx-close-tab-animation: NONE;");
```

The default setting is "GROW".

Comment: Are there any other settings (animations) that are available?

Answer (score 3):

Not easily. The animation logic is part of the TabPaneSkin:

From TabPane.java:

```
@Override protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
    return new TabPaneSkin(this);
}
```

But as far as I know, there is no way to make small adjustments to the default skin (which is hidden in the com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin package) but you'd have to implement a whole new skin.